# Cant get simple Oauth wth vertx to work with google

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, vert.x

Trying to create a web client that uses oauth to connect to multiple sso endopints, google mainly. This is on top of a spring boot project, I just keep getting the same error that no code is provided, but I'm not sure how i'm supposed to get a code without the access token first. Here is a simple version of what im trying to run I want localhost/8080 to redir to google to login and comeback to the same page or a different one doesn't matter

```
@RequestMapping("/google")
    fun google(@RequestParam(value = "code") code: String?, model: Model): String {

        val clientId = "asdf.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        val secret = "1234"

        var goog = GoogleAuth.create(Vertx.factory.vertx(), clientId, secret)

        goog.authenticate(JsonObject().put("code", code), {
            System.out.println(it)
        })

        return "test"


    }
```

the error is always

````
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code"
}}
e```

but how can I provide a code first I need some sort of response from the server. I'm pretty familiar with restful oauth and must be missing something
````

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `GoogleAuth` like that. `GoogleAuth` provides the basic primitives to handle the `OAuth2` protocol. As you're not using the `vertx-web` part you will need to setup a callback endpoint in your application (I guess it's the `/google` endpoint you listed) but now you miss the whole Oauth2 handshake. Your client (browser) should call Google, which calls your server to validate the code.

So what you're asking here is to re-implement the vert.x web Oauth2Handler using Spring Boot APIs.

Comment: Hmm, I sort of follow, so I sort of have the callback method in place but not sending the user to google to actually auth? Is there a more complete example somewhere using Oauth2Handler?

Comment: https://vertx-tutorials.jetdrone.xyz/tutorials/oauth2/github/ is an example using GitHub.